# Change a single parameter of Object in Hashmap

Tags: java, object, hashmap

I had to do a very basic "make a CAD project" for school and decided to make it a bit more challenging and add a way to interact more properly with the project.
Basically, I have a `Point` class with a constructor that takes `x` and `y` coordinates as input and also has some methods.

```java
Point(double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

I wanted the user to be able to create as many points as he/she desires - and thus I went to `Hashmaps` (I tried lists too but I've read that `Hashmaps` are better for this, even though I couldn't find concrete answers to what I want in my project).
The relevant snippet from my code looks as follows:

```java
Map<Integer, Point> pMap = new HashMap<Integer, Point>();
double[] singlePoints = new double[2]; // temporarily store x and y coordinates
...
...
...
switch (intInput) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("Create point? y/n");
        charInput = sc.next().charAt(0);
        if(java.lang.Character.toLowerCase(charInput) == 'y') {
            System.out.println("X coordinate: ");
            singlePoints[0] = sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Y coordinate: ");
            singlePoints[1] = sc.nextDouble();
            pMap.put(pointCounter, new point(singlePoints[0], singlePoints[1]));
            pointCounter ++;
            break;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Which point shall be edited?: ");
        int pointC2 = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("X or Y coordinate? ");
        char c2Input = java.lang.Character.toLowerCase(sc.next().charAt(0));
        if(c2Input == 'x') {
            ???
        }
}
```

The part with the question marks is where I want to change the `x` coordinate only. Since I haven't given the new `Point` (that is directly stored into the `Hashmap`) a name, I can't access it with my getter and setter methods.
How do I go on from here to change a single parameter (in this example it's 'x') of an object at a given index inside of the `Hashmap`? If it's not possible, should I go back to normal `Lists`, and if so, how would I do that?
(Also, a quick note: We haven't gotten to `Lists` or `Hashmaps` in the lectures as of now so my knowledge is based on what I found on the internet and doesn't come from experience or university)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user input the desired point in `pointC2` you might find the stored key in your map.

```java
Point selectedPoint = pMap.get(pointC2);
selectedPoint.setX(newX);

// pMap.get(pointC2).setX(newX);
```

You did store a key in

```java
pMap.put(pointCounter, new point(singlePoints[0], singlePoints[1]));
```

Your key is `pointCounter`